# Find Max : $P=\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{4}{y^2+4}+\frac{3z}{9+z^2}$

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$ and satisfying $3xy+yz+2zx=6$

Find Maximum of this expression: $P=\frac{1}{x^2+1}+\frac{4}{y^2+4}+\frac{3z}{9+z^2}$

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: Generically, this is a duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/796482/find-the-minimum-value-of-p-frac14x-y2-frac1xz2-frac1yz?rq=1) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230637/demand-z-xy-and-x2-4-y2-5-z2-25-1-what-is-the-maximum-value-of-f/1230694#1230694), which both use Lagrange multipliers. I'm closing this question as an abstract duplicate.